# python tornado websocket error on reconnect

Tags: python, tornado

Have this simple python code for a tornado websocket server.

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import time
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import *
import datetime

listeners = []


class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

  def open(self):
    print 'New connection was opened'
    self.write_message("Con!")
    listeners.append(self)


  def on_message(self, message):
    print 'Received:', message
    self.write_message("Received: " + message)
    for w in listeners:
        w.write_message('MASS MESSAGE')

  def on_close(self):
    print 'Con closed...'


  def trimite(self, msg):
    self.write_message(msg)


application = tornado.web.Application([
  (r'/ws', WSHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
  http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
  http_server.listen(65)
  tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Every time i execute a command from my webpage to the websocket server, a message is sent to all connections. it works ok...but, if i close and reconnect a client and i try to send another command, i get this error, and the connection closes. I have to restart the websocket server for it to work again. Any ideea why? thanks!

```
ERROR:root:Uncaught exception in /ws
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 258, in wrapper
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "ciuciu.py", line 26, in on_message
    w.write_message('MASS MESSAGE')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 144, in write_message
    self.ws_connection.write_message(message, binary=binary)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write_message'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out. I have to add listeners.remove:

```
  def on_close(self):
    listeners.remove(self)
    print 'Con closed...'
```